# The slowest Javascript Implementation in Browser

Tags: .net-framework, javascript, performance, browser

Is it Internet Explorer?  I heard that JScript.NET was there for a long time and with .NET, things can be JIT'ed.  Are we going to see JIT'ed javascript in IE soon?

Comment: Off topic: IE is going down the drain so I don't think you'll have to worry about this ;)

Comment: Look at the comparisons with IE9, they have made improvements that you can test out with the developer release.

Comment: Actually, what I am after is would there be a built-in javascript engine (just like the COM based Windows Scripting Host) available from Windows in the near future.  Because I am now considering the best way to embed a efficient Javascript engine in my own appli.

I can use the current COM based JScript (or VBScript) engine from Windows directly but it seems to be too slow for my need.  What I am after is something as fast as V8.

Comment: I would either ask a different question or edit this one if that's what you really want to know. As it is, this is about to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

> The slowest Javascript Implementation in Browser
>   Is it Internet Explorer?

JScript *is* somewhat slow. However, I'm not sure it is the slowest. There's *dozens* of JavaScript engines, it's pretty likely that there's one even crappier than JScript.

Although, it *is* hard to beat implementing objects as linked lists. That *is* probably the stupidest thing I've ever heard.

> I heard that JScript.NET was there for a long time and with .NET, things can be JIT'ed.

JScript.NET *is* faster than JScript, but Microsoft only allows you to use it on the server in ASP.NET, you can't use it in the browser.

> Are we going to see JIT'ed javascript in IE soon?

The Chakra engine in IE9 does JIT compilation. In fact, it is probably the fastest JavaScript engine right now, although benchmarking unreleased development code against stable releases is always unfair.